# TextView Update Content Every Second Via Sleep Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

in this app the Content of the TextView should change/update every second with a sleep thread.
The whole process starts when the button is clicked.

Firstable here is the normal code without the threads:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btn;
    TextView tw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                tw.setText("1");    //This is the TextView Content, it should update every second with a sleep thread
                tw.setText("2");
                tw.setText("3");





            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the code  added ( not working ) sleep threads:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btn;
    TextView tw;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw);


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                tw.setText("1");       


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                tw.setText("2");


                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                tw.setText("3");





            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank´s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are block the main UI(sleep) thread thus giving you unexpected result.

You need to use handler for this if you want to update this each second

**sample:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btn;
TextView tw;
int incre = 1; 
Handler handler;
Runnable run;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tw);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tw.setText(incre++ + "");
            handler = new Handler();
            run = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tw.setText(incre++ + ""); //set the textview text HERE every 1 second
                    if(incre != 3) //checks if it is not already 3 second
                         handler.postDelayed(run, 1000); //run the method again
                    else
                       incre -= 2;
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(run, 1000); //will call the runnable every 1 second


        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: But where do I have to put the Images ?

Comment: @ANDROID_DEV there is no images in your question above. If you mean images in your textView then put it in the run method

Comment: Sorry I mean my Content for the TextView

Comment: @ANDROID_DEV look at the `run` method ill comment it out for you see edit above.

Comment: I tried it, but the postDelayed in the run method is written in red Color.

Comment: @ANDROID_DEV make sure you import the right Handler: `import android.os.Handler;`

Comment: Thank´s I found, exactly! Thank´s man for help:) But theres still 1 Problem, the handler stops at 2 seconds and when you click it again the app works like a normal chronometer

Comment: @ANDROID_DEV if it helps you can upvote this post to mark as answered.Instead of `if(incre != 3)` you can say `if(incre != 4)` for three seconds

Comment: Thank´s, of course I will upvote it. And sorry I am a beginner and I sometimes do some pretty dumb mistakes.

Comment: Is it also possible to "reset" the timer after 4 seconds and then 2 more seconds and after that 3 seconds Count up automatically ?So:1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3

Comment: @ANDROID_DEV in the else part of the if statement deduct the `incre` to reset.

Comment: Could you please explain that?

Comment: like this tw.setText(incre-- - "");  ?

Comment: But that only resets the timer when the button is clicked again. Again When the 4 sec are over automatically the timer should reset and Count up 2---then it should reset again.

Comment: Can´t I add an onFinish() method for the run() method? The onFinish() Content would be: tw.setText("0"); . I tried but failed.

Comment: Done! Only had to add this if (incre==6){
                                incre-=5;
                                tw.setText("0");